# InAppSettingKit auto rotate issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, inappsettingskit

I am using IASK in my app, and I just found a problem. That is when I'm going to change my device orientation, and the main viewcontroller is working well (both iOS 5 & 6). But in the IASK view controller it doesn't work! In addition, the viewcontroller always splash flips the view when I press the settings button to get into the IASK view controller. I am trying to figure out what's wrong in my code. I did add both view orientation methods for iOS 5 & 6 into IASK view controller as well, but it still doesn't perform correctly.

Does anyone know how to solve this kind of problem?

```
//ios5 autorotate
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    if ((interfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait)||(interfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)) {
        return YES;
    }
    else return NO;
}

//ios6 autorotate

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortraitUpsideDown;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Did you try to reproduce this in the sample app?

Comment: not yet, but I am going to try that! Thank you.

Comment: Doesnt' work. even just use the IASK sample app.